# WPF ValueConverter vs MarkupExtension for DrawingImage Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, valueconverter, markup-extensions

I have a set of icons stored in a ResourceDictionary as `Geometry` objects. My intent is to use those to create icons for UI elements like buttons. I need to be able to customize those icons in various ways:

- Control Brush used to fill the geometry
- Control Outline rendering
- Be able to rotate / flip an icon
- etc.

Most UI elements that can present such icons are expecting `ImageSource` as the target type. Therefore I need a well-performing and easy-to-use mechanism for converting my `Geometry` resources into actual `ImageSource`s. In pseudo-code:
`ImageSource Convert(Geometry resource, RenderOptions options)` where `options` represent all kinds of customizations I may need like Brush, color, etc.

My understanding is that there are 2 general approaches: Markup Extensions and Value Converters. I have created 2 helper classes that derive from a common base. The base class actually defines conversion logic, while the 2 helpers provide MarkupExtension-specific and ValueConverter-specific functionality:

```
namespace MyWPFHelpers {

/// <summary>
/// Provides functionality for actual conversion. Also defines various options. In this example just Fill.
/// </summary>
public abstract class GeometryImageBase : MarkupExtension
{

    public Brush Fill { get; set; } = Brushes.Black;

    public DrawingImage CreateImage(Geometry g)
    {
        var d = new GeometryDrawing(Fill, null, g).FreezeAndReturn();
        var di = new DrawingImage(d).FreezeAndReturn();
        return di;
    }

}

[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(DrawingImage))]
public class GeometryImageExetnsion : GeometryImageBase
{

    public Geometry Value { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return CreateImage(Value);
    }

}

[ValueConversion(typeof(Geometry), typeof(DrawingImage))]
public class GeometryImageConverter : GeometryImageBase, IValueConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unfortunately we need to provide this since we inherit from GeometryImageBase that provides conversion functionality (which itself inherits from MarkupExtension)
    /// </summary>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return CreateImage((Geometry)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}


}
```

`FreezeAndReturn()` is just a simple helper method to Freeze an object and return it after it has been frozen.

Now, in the XAML markup, I can then use these classes as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:o="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfx="clr-namespace:MyWPFHelpers"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Geometry x:Key="myicongeometry" o:Freeze="True">M16,56L16,26 32,8 48,26 48,56 16,56z</Geometry>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" x:Key="mybrush" o:Freeze="True">
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
        <!-- Using Value Converter -->
        <Image Height="94" Width="95" Margin="207,98,215,127" 
            Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource myicongeometry},
            Converter={wpfx:GeometryImageConverter Fill={StaticResource mybrush}}}" />
        <!--
        Incidentally, for some reason the above line "Fill={StaticResource mybrush}"
        produces this error in VS 2015 and VS 2017:
        "Unknown property 'Fill' for type 'MS.Internal.Markup.MarkupExtensionParser+UnknownMarkupExtension' encountered while parsing a Markup Extension."
        However, if I change that line to say: "Fill=Red"
        everything works fine. However in both cases,
        the content is rendered correctly.
        Anyone knows why?
        -->


        <!-- Using Markup Extension -->
        <Image Source="{wpfx:GeometryImageExetnsion
        Fill={StaticResource mybrush},
        Value={StaticResource myicongeometry}}"
        Margin="352,107,70,118"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So now there are a few questions:

1. What is a better way from a performance perspective? This is a simplified example, and in real life there will be more properties than just `Fill`. Also, on a single Window there can easily be a few hundred icons of this sort. However icons themselves will not change during runtime (including fills and colors), so what is the best practice to minimize new object creation, and reuse existing DrawingImages where possible?
2. Are there any other differences one should be aware of? I prefer the Markup Extension syntax because it seems cleaner.
3. What about that weird `Fill` property not found error in VS on the ValueConverter? It won't compile because of this, but strangely enough it has no trouble at all rendering the correct brush (Fill) in the designer.
4. I know that Value Converters can be made into static application-wide resources, not so the Markup Extensions. So, will then me using ValueConverter as a static resource make things faster as opposed to Markup Extension (which I cannot turn into a resource)?
5. Any other considerations of when to use ValueConverter vs MarkupExtension for the binding of this kind (i.e. where a bit of transformation / conversion logic is involved)?

Comment: The Binding with value converter approach seems unnecessarily complex, considering the fact that the Source object of the Binding never changes. No need at all for a Binding.

Comment: @Clemens I cannot use `myicongeometry` in the `Source` property without a binding, because the `Source` property expects `ImageSource` not a `Geometry` object as its value.

Comment: What I was trying to say is, why at all have an approach with a Binding, when it works as well without a Binding, i.e. as in your second approach?

Comment: @Clemens Well that's what actually my question is about: the pros and cons of each. I am not very familiar with the nuances of WPF, and thus need a thorough answer on the performance impact and other pros and cons of both of these apparoaches.

Comment: Plus I am also not sure if my `CreateImage` actually does a good job in terms of a performance. How often will it get called for a given image control - icon combination in these 2 approaches. For one thing I don;t want ti to be called every time a control containing that image comes into view.

Comment: In both cases the CreateImage method is called exactly once per Image control instance (you could easily check that in your debugger). Besides that the second approach saves you a Binding object.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the tip. But then why use ValueConverters at all, if one can always write a custom MarkupExtension instead? Also, how many instances of both the ValueConverter and MarkupExtension are created - one for each image in all cases?

Comment: You may need a value converter for a Binding. A MarkupExtension won't help when you need to convert the bound value.